# What does: "moments only exist for order less than $1 / \xi$" mean? (concerning the Fréchet distribution)

Tags: statistics, terminology, extreme-value-theorem

Could someone please help me out with this sentence. Whilst I understand the first part, I don't understand the last part in bold.

"The Fréchet distribution ($\xi >
0$) has a heavy tail with $1 − G_\xi (x) \sim ( \xi x) ^ {−1/ \xi}$ as $x \to \infty$, and, hence,
**moments only exist for order less than $1 / \xi $.**"

Particularly, what does "order less than $1 / \xi$" mean?

Comment: It suggests that $E[X^k]$  is finite when $0<k < 1/\xi$ and not finite when $k\ge 1/\xi$